# iOS iAd is working inconsistently

Tags: ios, iad

As I said my iAd is working sometimes but sometimes its not working.It usually works during the first simulator run but if I begin to open different pages it begin not to work so my codes forces banner to close itself(apple rules).Its really strange cause I dont know why its doing this sometimes it works without any problem no matter how many view controllers I pass it keeps working but if it begin to not work then it keeps not working for many viewcontrollers(which has different h and m files) then suddenly it begins to work and after couple of successful ad showing it begins not work again.I can say that its working succses is below %40 so I have to solve it.

Is this something related to apple iad servers ?

I am testing my app on simulator 5.1 and I can only receive iad testing ads for my banner so can they be the reason of this strange problem ?

Is it a normal thing for iAd ?

Is my code is the one to blame is it missing something ?

Is it about relasing iAd or can I force it to try to open iad again ?

If you know your way around about this iad please help me !

h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface a1viewcontroller : UIViewController < UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate > {



  ADBannerView *banner;    

}

@property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL bannerIsVisible;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;



@end
```

m file

```
@synthesize banner, bannerIsVisible;

-(void)bannerViewDidLoad: (ADBannerView *)abanner {

    if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, 50.0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }


}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)aBanner {

    if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, -320.0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }

}
```

The code is same for other view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to see what the problem is with your banner.

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Make sure you did set the delegate of your bannerview.

My guess is that's related to the iAd server.
(don't know if much changed in iOS 6 though.)

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation says:

> "While you are developing your application, iAd Network sends test advertisements to your application. To assist you in validating your implementation, the iAd Network occasionally returns errors to test your error handling code."

Also in my app iad return a mix of correct banner,error 3,error 5...

I think that this problem will disapper after the release of the app when iAd will change from "iAd Network serves test ads" to "iAd Network serves live ads if you signed the iAd Network Agreement and enabled advertising for your application"